# sidebar-mini is overlayed by navbarPage in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to add a navbarPage and use a slidebar-mini class, however when the sidebar is minimized the menu item text are under navbarpage items, which is not correct. any idea how one can bring the items on top of the navbarpage menu ?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(tags$script(
    HTML("$('body').addClass('sidebar-mini ');")
  ),

  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('Test', icon = icon('phone'), tabName = 'sampletabname')
  )),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs() ,



                tabItems(tabItem(
                  "sampletabname",

                  navbarPage(
                    title = div(icon("jsfiddle"), "test1 "),


                    tabPanel(
                      title = " test2" ,
                      value = "Connection",
                      icon = icon("database")
                    ),
                    tabPanel(
                      title = " test3" ,
                      value = "Filtering",
                      icon = icon("filter")

                    )

                  )

                )))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the functionality of [ShinyDashboardPlus](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/)?

Comment: Hi @TanHo, Not really, I have seen the ShinyDashboardPlus, but this style which I have is not available there. especially the navbarPage inside the tab...